# Terraform - editing EKS managed node groups triggers RBAC permission errors

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, rbac

With Terraform I deployed a Kubernetes cluster in AWS (EKS) and everything worked smoothly. The problem arise whenever I try to change a node group or to create a new node group.

### The Context:

I used the following code:

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.15.3"

  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.27"

  # EKS Addons
  cluster_addons = {
    
    coredns = {
      most_recent = true  # To ensure access to the latest settings provided
    }

    kube-proxy = {
      most_recent = true  # To ensure access to the latest settings provided
    }


    vpc-cni = {
      # Specify the VPC CNI addon should be deployed before compute to ensure
      # the addon is configured before data plane compute resources are created
      before_compute = true
      most_recent    = true  # To ensure access to the latest settings provided
      configuration_values = jsonencode({
      })
    }
  }

  vpc_id                         = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids                     = module.vpc.private_subnets
  cluster_endpoint_public_access = true

  # Calico needs VXLAN communication between nodes
  node_security_group_additional_rules = {

    ingress_self_all = {
      description = "Node to node all ports/protocols"
      protocol    = "-1"
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      type        = "ingress"
      self        = true
    }

    ingress_cluster_to_node_all = {
      description                   = "API Server to nodes all ports/protocols"
      protocol                      = "-1"
      from_port                     = 0
      to_port                       = 0
      type                          = "ingress"
      source_cluster_security_group = true
    }

    egress_all = {
      description      = "Node all egress"
      protocol         = "-1"
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      type             = "egress"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    }
  }

  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {

    default_nodes_groups = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]

      min_size     = 3
      max_size     = 3
      desired_size = 3
    }

  }

  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true
  aws_auth_roles = [
    {
      rolearn  = module.eks_admins_iam_role.iam_role_arn
      username = module.eks_admins_iam_role.iam_role_name
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
  ]
}
```

The VPC is pretty basic and for the IAM roles to be associated with RBAC system:masters I followed this reference that is pretty detailed: [reference link](https://antonputra.com/amazon/create-eks-cluster-using-terraform-modules/#create-eks-using-terraform)

Basically, I:

1. create a IAM policy with approprate permissions to eks and iam
2. create an assumable role with the policy (the role placed above in the `aws_auth_roles` part)
3. create a policy that allow users to assume that role
4. create a group that has this assume-role policy and the admin user (for kubectl access... for Terraform access through the Kubernetes provider the role in "2." is enough)

Then, using these Terraform can interact with the cluster during creation/edits:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "default" {
  name = var.cluster_name

  depends_on = [ module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups, ]
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
}   

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
  }
}
```

Finally I add calico and AWS load balancer controller

```
# Calico addon to exploit Network Security Policies in EKS
module "kubernetes_addons_calico" {
  count  = var.calico_network_policies_enabled ? 1 : 0
  source = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints//modules/kubernetes-addons?ref=v4.32.1"

  eks_cluster_id = module.eks.cluster_name

  enable_calico = true

  calico_helm_config = {
    name       = "calico"                                # (Required) Release name.
    repository = "https://docs.projectcalico.org/charts" # (Optional) Repository URL where to locate the requested chart.
    chart      = "tigera-operator"                       # (Required) Chart name to be installed.
    version    = "v3.26.1"                               # (Optional) Specify the exact chart version to install.
    namespace  = "tigera-operator"                       # (Optional) The namespace to install the release into.
    values = [
      <<-EOT
          installation:
            kubernetesProvider: EKS
        EOT
    ]
  }

}

module "lb_role" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks"
  version = "5.28.0"

  role_name                              = "${var.cluster_name}-load-balancer-controller"
  attach_load_balancer_controller_policy = true

  oidc_providers = {
    main = {
      provider_arn               = module.eks.oidc_provider_arn
      namespace_service_accounts = ["kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller"]
    }
  }
}

# Deploy the AWS Load Balancer Controller
# it creates also the service-role
resource "helm_release" "lb_controller" {
  name       = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  version    = "1.5.5"
  namespace  = "kube-system"

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = var.cluster_name
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = module.lb_role.iam_role_arn
  }
}
```

### The Problem:

Everything works fine and I manage to do all my things on the cluster. Nevertheless, if I try to add a node to the node group, or to create a new node group I get the following errors:

```
│ Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "tigera-operator"
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.module.kubernetes_addons_calico[0].module.calico[0].module.helm_addon.helm_release.addon[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/k8s_control_plane.kubernetes_addons_calico/modules/kubernetes-addons/helm-addon/main.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "addon":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "addon" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: configmaps "aws-auth" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/k8s_control_plane.eks/main.tf line 553, in resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth":
│  553: resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.module.eks.aws_eks_addon.before_compute["vpc-cni"],
│   on .terraform/modules/k8s_control_plane.eks/main.tf line 420, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "before_compute":
│  420:   resolve_conflicts        = try(each.value.resolve_conflicts, "OVERWRITE")
│ 
│ The "resolve_conflicts" attribute can't be set to "PRESERVE" on initial
│ resource creation. Use "resolve_conflicts_on_create" and/or
│ "resolve_conflicts_on_update" instead
╵
╷
│ Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.helm_release.lb_controller,
│   on ../../../modules/eks-ctrl-plane/aws-lb.tf line 26, in resource "helm_release" "lb_controller":
│   26: resource "helm_release" "lb_controller" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["kube-proxy"],
│   on .terraform/modules/k8s_control_plane.eks/main.tf line 392, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "this":
│  392:   resolve_conflicts        = try(each.value.resolve_conflicts, "OVERWRITE")
│ 
│ The "resolve_conflicts" attribute can't be set to "PRESERVE" on initial
│ resource creation. Use "resolve_conflicts_on_create" and/or
│ "resolve_conflicts_on_update" instead
╵
╷
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.k8s_control_plane.module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["coredns"],
│   on .terraform/modules/k8s_control_plane.eks/main.tf line 392, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "this":
│  392:   resolve_conflicts        = try(each.value.resolve_conflicts, "OVERWRITE")
│ 
│ The "resolve_conflicts" attribute can't be set to "PRESERVE" on initial
│ resource creation. Use "resolve_conflicts_on_create" and/or
│ "resolve_conflicts_on_update" instead
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)
```

Note that the Warnings were there in the previously successful runs and I am pretty sure they are harmless (I put them for the sake of completeness).

The main two changes I tried to do (not together) are:

```
    default_nodes_groups = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]

      min_size     = 3
      max_size     = 5
      desired_size = 5
    }
```

and:

```
eks_managed_node_groups = {

    default_nodes_groups = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]

      min_size     = 3
      max_size     = 3
      desired_size = 3
    }

    extra_nodes_groups = {
      name = "node-group-2"

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1
    }

  }
```

With those changes everything fails pretty much in the same way.

I have pretty much no idea on what could be the issue, I tried updating, I went back and forth to try to understand why these changes are performed with a **system:anonymous** user but I don't really get it. Also why that change requires querying secrets in the cluster and why those queries are performed somehow not with the Kubernetes provider that has all permissions to do that!

I thought the Kubernetes operations were performed through the Kubernetes provider that has **system:masters** RBAC permission (in fact I can update all addons/resources, create/destroy them, etc.), but it seems that the node groups changes are using something else. I tried to check permissions on the Terraform user, but it already has the Full Admin policy, so it can basically do whatever it wants on EKS if that change is performed through its IAM permission.

My only concern is if, somehow, only during edits (not creation... those queries are weird), the EKS module uses the Terraform user (and not the Kubernetes provider with the assume-role with RBAC **system:mastes** permissions) to interact with the Kubernetes API and edit the cluster (that would explain the **system:anonymous**)... but it seems mental to me that this could be the issue, I mean why would it be different to change the cluster compared to create it in the first place?

Does anyone have a clue on what could be the issue and how to fix this to be able to scale up and down the nodes manually from Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `depends_on = [ module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups, ]` from `aws_eks_cluster_auth`.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10362#issuecomment-543801371

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).